# Will Instagram's API allow a web app to send, respond, and archive DMs?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am interested in building a tool that allows business to manage DMs from a web app.

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience working with Instagram's API in this capacity, and if so, whether there is any red tape to be aware of.

I very much appreciate the insights!

Comment: Nope. Can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you mind letting me know why? I'd be happy to pay for 10 mins of your time on a call :-).

Comment: Not much "why" to it. Instagram doesn't let you do anything with DMs via the API. It's simply not in the public API, likely due to spam concerns. Their API is heavily limited - you can't even upload images through it. All the supported actions are at https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no API for Instagram DMs. There has been no mention of opening up in the future, either.